# java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: id.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds

Tags: android, timeoutexception, finalize

Our company's app encountered a crash, but this problem is not necessarily present, I can not reproduce the problem now, we can provide me with the next solution to ideas

id.finalize() id  is RandomAccessFile's Subclass .

this STACK_TRACE is :

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: id.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
at libcore.io.Posix.fstat(Native Method)
at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.fstat(ForwardingOs.java:56)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:60)
at libcore.io.IoUtils.close(IoUtils.java:43)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.close(RandomAccessFile.java:166)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.finalize(RandomAccessFile.java:175)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:194)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:176)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: maybe stream is not close ,maybe resource not release

Comment: @WangLiu Please write in english. Everybody should understand what you are saying. You characters show up as foreign (maybe asian?) symbols.

Comment: Sorry ,I can not reproduce, you can suggest the next method?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like broken memory that caused writes to it to take too long. Happens when you use bad sd cards. You should do a stress test and write many bytes to a file and close it.